# Implementing an Android library project

Tags: android, project

I have an android project that I want to "clone" for a second similar project which only differs by one file: it's sqlite database (assets/mydata.sql).

I've turned the source project (reslib) into a library and added it to my clone project's properties (the source project shows up under "Library Projects" as reslib.jar)

Thing is, I'm not sure how to launch the main activity in the source project. The source project's main activity sets-up a TabHost. How do I launch into the source project's main activity from my clone project? I started pasting code into "cloneActivity.java" to fire up the TabHost but then wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Any specific reason why you opted for library? Are these two projects inter-dependent? If not, why not you have rename with project and changes required files? When you upload this to market, anyway it will be new APK right?

Comment: I am trying to share code between projects. Making a shared common library (project) was the only way I could find to create a shared codebase between two projects.

Comment: Then I am sorry I don't have any answer. In my case, I maintained two source code bases. By the way which allowed me to add extra features to one of the app which are not required for others. I strongly suggest same for you too. Who knows, in future you may faces same situation.

Comment: Maintaining two separate code bases appears to be the only way to make it work with Eclipse. Using a JAR file from source project does not allow for shared resource files (res/drawable/) and I am running into many compile problems with the Project Library. I don't know if they are my fault or just buggy Eclipse/ADT.

Comment: As far as I know you can add only 'src' package as JAR. You can't add other packages as JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is pretty straight-forward. In the manifest for your dependent project, you need to specify the source project's activity as the one you want to launch.

Suppose your source project has package name `com.example.source`, your dependent project has package name `com.example.dependent`, and the main activity in your source project is `MainActivity.java`.

Then in AndroidManifest.xml in your dependent project, you would have something like the following:

```
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/logo" >
  <activity
     android:name="com.example.source.MainActivity" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <!-- possibly lots more activities and other declarations -->

</application>
```

**Important Notes:** In the manifests for both your source project and the dependent project, you must make sure to list all activities, permissions, etc.  If later on you add an activity to your source project, you'll need to remember to add it to the dependent project's manifest as well.

Also, you'll need to copy anything in the source project's assets directory to the dependent project—and don't forget to keep that in sync as well. (*This is true as of June 2012, I've heard that some future version of the Android build tools will likely alleviate this headache.*)

And finally, if you use Eclipse to create the projects, it will create a default layout `main.xml`.  Since resources in the dependent project override resources in the source project, make sure this doesn't trip you up.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating an activity in the dependent project which launched the startup Activity in the library project. Not the best but all I could figure out at the time. I like this way much better!